# How to declare multiprovider in some other class than main.dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

i'm trying to create a multiprovider in a class. but it doesn't work same as declaring multiproviders in main.dart above material app.

```
class Chat extends StatelessWidget {
 const Chat({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ChatProvider>( create: (context) => ChatProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<MessageProvider>( create: (context) => MessageProvider()),
      ],
      child: ChatMainScreen(),
      
      // MaterialApp(
      //     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //     home: ChatMainScreen(),
      // )
    );
  }
}
```

I'm navigating to another screen from ChatMainScreen to a new screen(ChatRoom) where this issue arises.(ChatMainScreen => ChatRoom)

if i wrap my ChatMainScreen with another material app than it seems to work. but is it ok to have another material app inside a material app?.

Also with material app parent to ChatMainScreen routing back is not working correctly. if i press back button from ChatRoom screen, instead of getting popped back to chatMainScreen, it is popped out to the screen from where i pushed to ChatMainScreen

Comment: where are you calling Provider.of?? Is it maybe on another route?

Comment: yes, calling it on the new route pushed

Comment: Yes to use a provider on many routes you have to put the multiprovider above a material app because the different routes are children of the material app.

Comment: so, then how to overcome the issue that when i press back button it gets popped from the main screen, instead of going back to previous route?

and what about using material app inside another material app, is this a good approach?

Comment: probably bad idea to use more than one `MaterialApp`, it has unintended consequences. Why not pass the providers as values to the new route? Like you would if you didn't have a provider?

Answer (score 5):

When using `Provider` understanding the `context` is important. To have access to a Provider everywhere you can put it above the `MaterialApp` and it works fine. Now `MaterialApp` from flutter is most certainly creating a `Navigator` object internally so that it can maintain a stack of the child routes and having the `MultiProvider` above this object allows you to have access to these Providers.

In your case it seems you don't want to have the Providers above the MaterialApp, so I can think of two solutions:

1. In your `Chat` widget you have created the `MultiProvider` and used `ChatMainScreen` widget as the child so this is good because in your  `ChatMainScreen` widget's context is below the `MultiProvider` so you have access to it. Somewhere in your `ChatMainScreen` you push another route which opens `ChatRoom` widget. If you want access to the Providers mentioned in `MultiProvider` you need to push a `MultiProvider` like:

```dart
Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Provider.of<ChatProvider>(context,
                  listen: false),
          ...
           ],
          child: ChatRoom()
```

Using `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` will give you access to the same Provider in the new route.

2. Creating a new Navigator stack yourself in the `Chat` widget.

```dart
 return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ChatProvider>( create: (context) => ChatProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<MessageProvider>( create: (context) => MessageProvider()),
      ],
      child: Navigator(
              onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                return MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return ChatMainScreen();
      
     
    );
```

I think the 1st solution might be better for you and you should not have more than 1 `MaterialApp` widget in your app.